# Continuity of line integral as a function of path

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis

Let's consider a line integral as a function of the curve:
$$I(\gamma) = \int_{\gamma}f(\gamma(s))ds.$$ If $f$ isn't continuous, it's easy to prove that $I$ isn't continuous either (in any reasonable sense). Is anything known about the continuity of $I$ when $f$ is continuous? For what I need, the domain of $I$ can be the family of smooth open curves $\gamma \colon [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: What topology do you take on the space of (admissible) paths?

Comment: @DanielFischer Something like topology of uniform convergence should be OK if my topology skills aren't failing me. But if you know the answer for  some other nontrivial topology, let me know.

Comment: Hang on a moment. You wrote $\int_{\gamma} f(\gamma(s))\,ds$, which doesn't quite make sense. Did you mean $\int_0^1 f(\gamma(s))\,ds$ or a path integral, $\int_{\gamma} f(x)\,d\vec{x} = \int_0^1 \langle f(\gamma(s)), \gamma'(s)\rangle\,ds$ (if $f$ is a vector field) resp. $\int_{\gamma} f(x) \,\lvert d\vec{x}\rvert = \int_0^1 f(\gamma(s))\cdot \lvert \gamma'(s)\rvert\,ds$ (if $f$ is real-valued)?

Comment: Wait, a moment.

Comment: Then you're safe, uniform convergence of paths is enough for continuity of $I(\gamma)$. Given $\gamma_0$, take a compact neighbourhood $K$ of $\gamma_0([0,1])$. Since $f$ is continuous, it is uniformly continuous on $K$. All paths close to $\gamma_0$ stay in $K$.

Comment: Sorry, I got it wrong in that comment. What I have is a typical line integral, i.e. $\int_0^1 f(\gamma(s)) |\gamma'(s)| ds$. And $f\colon \mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Well, since the curve is smooth, that additional term ($|\gamma'(s)|$) is bounded, so it shouldn't be a problem for continuity, right?

Comment: The term $|\gamma'(s)|$ is not necessarily uniformly bounded. Take a sequence of high oscillating curves converging to $\gamma$. I guess this already gives you a counter example: Take $f \equiv 1$ so that you are, in fact dealing with the length of curves. It is known that length of curves is lower semicontinuous, but it is not necessarily continuous. Again, high oscillating curves may converge uniformly to a curve while having lengths which are much higher than the length of the limit curve.

Comment: For $\int_0^1 f(\gamma(s))\cdot \lvert\gamma'(s)\rvert\,ds$ you need also consider the derivative of the curves to have continuous dependence on the path.

Comment: Thank you for help, I'll try to finish this myself.

Comment: @matb: Have you read my comment? If you only consider uniform convergence of the paths, the integrals are not continuous. For $f \equiv 1$, for example you only have lower semicontinuity, You should consider convergence in the $C^1$ norm if you want continuity.

Comment: @BeniBogosel Yes, I did. But I was thinking about approaching my problem a bit differently. It looks like considering the $C^1$ norm would do the trick too. Thanks!